# How do I collect a message inside of an interaction event in discord js?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create an anti-bot feature where a user has to repeat what the bot says back at it after calling the bot with a slash command. I need to wait for a reply for x seconds, and if there's no response cancel the command. I'm using the discord event called on interactionCreate, so I don't have access to a message object from which to instantiate a collector from. I've looked through the documentation, and I'm unable to find a way to get follow up responses from the user. Here's my code:

```
} else if (commandName === 'mine') {
        var isBot = true;
        var increase;
        const db = getDatabase();
        const dbref = ref(db);

        if (talkedRecently.has(interaction.user.id) && interaction.user.username != "Nurav") {
            interaction.reply("Hold up, wait 1 minute before typing mine.");
        } else {

            increase = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
            interaction.reply(`Please complete your mine by sending this number: ${increase}`);

            Here is where I need to wait for their response and check whether it's equal to the number I sent earlier.
If they sent the right thing, I need to set isBot to false.

            if (!isBot) {
                get(child(dbref, `users/` + interaction.user.username)).then((snapshot) => {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        var newBal = snapshot.val().balance + increase;

                        if (!snapshot.val().banned) {

                            set(ref(db, 'users/' + interaction.user.username), {
                                username: interaction.user.username,
                                balance: newBal
                            });

                            const accountEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                                .setColor('#ff5500')
                                .setTitle("Success!")
                                .setURL('https://ascent-projects-64363.web.app/')
                                .setAuthor({ name: 'Central Bank Of Firecoin', iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/888920833769242688/925485246974156860/Asset_44x.png', url: 'https://ascent-projects-64363.web.app/' })
                                .setDescription('+' + increase.toString())
                                .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/888920833769242688/925485246974156860/Asset_44x.png')
                                .setTimestamp()
                                .setFooter('Central Bank Of Firecoin', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/888920833769242688/925485246974156860/Asset_44x.png');

                            interaction.reply({ embeds: [accountEmbed] });
                        }
                        else {
                            interaction.reply("Your account has been flagged for botting. To appeal the flag, message Nurav#4295");
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("No data available");
                        interaction.reply("Account doesn't exist");
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            }

            // Adds the user to the set so that they can't talk for a minute
            talkedRecently.add(interaction.user.id);
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Removes the user from the set after a minute
                talkedRecently.delete(interaction.user.id);
            }, 60000);
        }

        //Ant-Bot confirmation
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working. Farther up in my code, I had it set so that any interaction that wasn't a command was returned:
`if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextChannel.createMessageCollector`.

It creates a message collector at the channel, collects `MESSAGES_TO_COLLECT` messages that satisfies filter for `SECONDS_TO_REPLY` seconds, and when finished, emits `end` event.

You can also use `collect` event to do something when a message is collected. However, in this case, we collect only one message, so no need to use `collect` event.

So the code would be:

```js
const SECONDS_TO_REPLY = 60 // replace 60 with how long to wait for message(in seconds).
const MESSAGES_TO_COLLECT = 1
const filter = (m) => m.author.id == interaction.user.id
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({filter, time: SECONDS_TO_REPLY * 1000, max: MESSAGES_TO_COLLECT})
collector.on('end', collected => {
if (collected.size > 0 && collected.first().content == increase) {
  // not a robot
  // do all stuffs here without using isBot
}
/*
// uncomment to do something when robot is detected
else {
  
}
*/
```

replace the value of `SECONDS_TO_REPLY` with how long to wait for message(in seconds).

Comment: Can you explain how the filter is able to access a message object even though its inside an interaction? When I tried to use your solution, the collector doesn't seem to be collecting anything. This is the event listener I'm using: `client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {`

Comment: @Ascent my code collects messages in the same channel of interaction. And the `m` object is the message object to be collected. This way it can collect messages of the channel with same user. And did you put all the code of `if (!isBot)` in `if (collected.size > 0 && ...)`? Or try inserting `console.log(collected)` right before `if (collected.size > 0 && ...)`.